# AJAX call does not post the data

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am developing a web site with Code Igniter 2.1.3. I am using an AJAX call to post data to my controller, but for some reason the data is not being sent.

I am using AJAX calls all over the application and they all work well, just not this one.

My view:

```
<div id="ajaxResult">
<div class="page-header"><h2>Review Comments</h2></div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<?php if(count($comments)): ?>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>IP Address</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Comment</th>
<th>Approve</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $comment->comment_author_email; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $comment->comment_author_IP; ?></td>
<td>
<?php
$date = new DateTime($comment->comment_date);
$date = $date->format('d/m/Y');
echo $date;
?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php
$approve = array(
'name' => 'comment_approved',
'class' => 'approve',
'value' => '1',
'data-commentid' => $comment->id
);
echo form_checkbox($approve);
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php else: ?>
<p>No comments were found for review.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function()
{
$('.approve').on('click', function()
{
var id = $(this).data('commentid'); alert(id);
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo site_url('blog/admin/review_comment'); ?>",
type:'POST',
data: { comment_id: id },
success: function(data) { $('#ajaxResult').html(data); } // End of success function of ajax form
}); // End of ajax call
});
});
</script>
```

My controller function:

```
public function review_comment()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->model('blog_comment_m');
if(isset($_POST['comment_id']))
{
$id = $this->input->post('comment_id');
$data['comment_approved'] = 1;
$this->blog_comment_m->save($data, $id);
$this->data['comments'] = $this->blog_comment_m->get_by(array('comment_approved'=>0));
$this->load->view('admin/review_comments', $this->data);
}
else
{
$this->data['comments'] = $this->blog_comment_m->get_by(array('comment_approved'=>0));
$this->data['subview'] = 'admin/review_comments';
$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
}
```

I tried to alert the comment_id and it does give me a value of 1. In the controller I do `var_dump($_POST)`, always empty.

I also tried `if(isset($_POST['comment_id']))`. In the controller it never goes into the `if(isset($_POST['comment_id'])` statement.

Why is that?

Comment: The best way to determine if the data is being sent or not is examine the `network` layer. `Firebug addon` of `firefox`, `chrome` (right click -> Inspect element -> Network tab), or install `fiddler` http://fiddler2.com/. Please confirm that the data is not being sent over the network layer. Otherwise, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: You can see sends & gets in Console tab too.

Comment: If I look at the NET tab in firebug I see this: Status: 302 error found (Read about that, I am not redirecting anything not sure why I get this error. In the Post tab I see this: Parameters comment_id = 1 Source comment_id = 1 So it all looks fine to me? Is there anything else I should check? Thank you very much

Comment: Now you have to check why you get 302. Maybe you have redirection in `.htaccess` or CI make some redirection - for example to login page because ajax have no admin privilage). Get url used in ajax and test it directly in another browser (without cookies, session from your page). You can also use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) in command line to test that url. Btw: where is your ajax code ?

Comment: Hi furas, thank you. I went to the url directly in another browser while logged in as admin and it worked fine. I would not be able to go to the view if I was not logged in as admin. My ajax code is in the view at the bottom, you can see it in my question. This is so frustrating... My htaccess file: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt|captcha)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: OHHHH ! I FOUND IT!!!!

Oh dear, oh dear, it was the fact that I started using csrf on form submits, a new thing for me, and I didn't add this url to the config file.

Adding this:
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('blog/admin/review_comment');
Solved the problem......

OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH :)

Thank you very very much for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

It was the fact that I started using csrf on form submits, a new thing for me, and I didn't add this url to the config file.

Adding this:

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('blog/admin/review_comment');
```

Solved the problem......

Thank you very very much for all the help.

Comment: When you can, accepting this answer by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: Will do tomorrow, it doesn't let me do it today... ;)